# Some thoughts about generating random number

Tags: javascript, random

I wanted some information about generating random integers. I look for it in `Google` and `Stack Overflow` and mostly found code like this (in case we want numbers from 1 to 52):

```
var randInt=function(){
   number=Math.floor(Math.random()*52+1);
};
```

and

```
var randNumMin = 1;
var randNumMax = 52;
var randInt = function (){
   number = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (randNumMax - randNumMin + 1)) + randNumMin);
};
```

I read some references about `Math.random` and found that it is generating numbers from `0` to `1`. In case `Math.random` generates `1`, we will get number `5`, so it means we will get error. I agree that it is very rare case, but it is possible. I slightly modified code to avoid that error (in our case generation of number `53`). Here I think is a right code for generation random numbers in JavaScript. In your examples it generates only integers but I think it is possible to modify code and generate any kind of number:

```
var randInt = function(){
    number = Math.floor(Math.random()*52+1);
    if (number === 53){
       randInt();
    }
};
```

and

```
var randNumMin = 1;
var randNumMax = 52;
var randInt = function (){
    number = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (randNumMax - randNumMin + 1)) + randNumMin);
    if (number===53){
        randInt();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `Math.random()` function generates random numbers `x` where `0 <= x < 1`. So it will never generate *exactly* 1, although it might come really close.

From [the documentation for `random`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random):

> Returns a floating-point, pseudo-random number in the range `[0, 1)` that is, from 0 (inclusive) up to but not including 1 (exclusive), which you can then scale to your desired range.

Answer (score 2):

Just take your first code sample, and subtract one from the 52. The general formula is this:

```
random number between X and Y = (Y - X) * Math.random() + X
```

or for integers,

<s>Math.round((Y - X) * Math.random() + X)</s>

or to be more accurate (as pointed out by @Guffa),

```
Math.floor((Y-(X-1)) * Math.random() + X)
```

Comment: No, that will generate a random number between X and X+Y.

Comment: @Guffa no, it wont. Note the (Y - 1)

Comment: @Guffa the OP's formula would have returned that. Hence the question being posted on SO

Comment: You are missing the point completely. The code doesn't return a random number between X and Y, it returns a random number between X and **X+Y**.

Comment: @Guffa Sure? Let x = 1, y = 10, and Math.random() = 1 (for a maximum). I'll let you do the math.

Comment: Let x = 10, y = 20, and Math.random() = 1, gives 19*1+10 = 29, which is more than 20.

Comment: @Guffa oh, maybe I *was* missing the point. The example I used started out being specific to this question and then I changed it to be generic and forgot to update. It's edited and correct, now

Comment: Don't use `round`, it will make the lowest and highest number appear half as often as the other numbers.

Comment: @Guffa true also. Never thought about that one.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use floor because it will cut down the result indeed.

just use `round`

Math.round(Math.random(51))+1